# Need help of calculating the complexity of a code

Tags: c, complexity-theory

I have a small code that I need to know the complexity of and can't figure it out myself, can someone help/guide me to the solution?

```
int funn(int n) {
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = n / 2; i <= n; i++)
        for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2)
            k = k + n / 2;
    return k;
}
```

at first, I thought that the complexity is O(n) but there are some multiplications that I'm not sure of.
I'm new to that stuff so I need a guidance

Comment: would be good if you could explain how you arrived at O(n), and where exactly your doubt arises from. Otherwise, this is too broad, and will be closed as such. Also, this can only be C or C++.

Comment: How many iterations do the outer and inner loop perform when considered separately? What is the total number of iterations inside the inner loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop is (n/2) which is O(n).  The inner loop is O(log n).

So the whole thing is O(n log n).